# perl regex substitution if NOT this string NOR that character

Tags: regex, string, perl, regex-lookarounds, substitution

I'm using Perl to highlight errors through my browser as I scan through pages of text. At this point, I want to ensure the text `Seq` is preceded by a maltese cross and space `✠` , otherwise highlight it. I also want to ignore `n>Seq`.

PS. If it's easier, I want to ignore `>` but it will always be `n>`. In fact, it would always be `</span>` - whichever is easiest to check for.

Example phrase: `✠ Seq. S. Evangélii sec. Joánnem. — In illo témpore`

I'm trying to replace `xySeq` if `xy` is NOT a Maltese cross and a space `✠` , AND if `xy` is NOT the letter `n` and a greater than symbol `n>`.

In other words, I don’t want to substitute

```
✠ Seq  
n>Seq  
>Seq  
</span>Seq
```

but I do want to replace things like

```
✠Seq  
* Seq  
a✠Seq  
>aSeq
```

The following would work if I was just checking for single characters like `✠` or `>`

```perl
my $span_beg = q(<span class='bcy'>); # HTML markup for highlighting
my $span_end = q(</span>);
$phr =~ s/([^✠>]Seq)/$span_beg$1$span_end/g;
```

but `[^✠ >]Seq` will naturally only treat the ✠ and the space as one or the other.

I even tried `[^(✠\s)>]Seq` and a varible [^$var>] but these didn’t work.

I played with `(?<!✠\s)Seq` but didn't know how to incorporate `>` or if it was even the right way to go.

I hope this is possible, thanks for all.
Guy

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to tag `Seq` and exactly two characters before it, a couple of look-behinds might be enough:

```
s{..(?<!✠\s)(?<!n>)Seq}{$span_beg$&$span_end}g;
```

Or, with look-ahead:

```
s{(?!✠\s)(?!n>)..Seq}{$span_beg$&$span_end}g;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be more efficient than performing lookaround at every position:

```perl
# Doesn't include preceding characters in the span.
s{(✠ |>)?Seq}{ $1 ? $& : "$span_beg$&$span_end" }eg
```

```perl
# Includes two preceding characters in the span.
s{(?:(✠ |>)|..)Seq}{ $1 ? $& : "$span_beg$&$span_end" }seg
```

Comment: Thank you :) All the examples given work for me. I'm just running locally so performance is not an issue. I like the s{ }{ } but I think my Apache Perl on Windows only allows s///.

Comment: Nope, nothing special about Windows builds of Perl, at least not when it comes to the substitute operator.